# Python3: Catch SIGTTOU from subprocess and print warning

Tags: python, signals

Hello I have a problem with a small debug GUI I have written (using PySimpleGUI). Part of the GUI is the capability to call a local Linux shell command.

One of the shell commands/programs I want to execute returns a SIGTTOU signal, if I start the GUI in background (with &). Which will freeze the GUI until I bring the GUI to foreground with 'fg'.

Since it's kind of normal to start the GUI in background, **I just want to catch the SIGTTOU signal, print a warning and continue.**

The following code snippet kind of works, but leaves the shell commands as zombies (and I get no return value from the commands. What even works better is to use `signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, signal.SIG_IGN)` but I really want to print a warning. Is that possible? What does signal.SIG_IGN to remove the zombies?

```
        cmd_output = collections.deque()

        ...

        def _handle_sigttou(signum, frame):

            sys.__stdout__.write('WARNING: <SIGTTOU> received\n')

        def _run_shell_command(cmd, timeout=None):

            # run command
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

            # process output
            for line in p.stdout:
                line = line.decode(errors='backslashreplace').rstrip()
                cmd_output.appendleft((f'{line}'))

            # wait for return code
            retval = p.wait(timeout)

            # print result
            cmd_output.appendleft((f'✘ ({retval})') if retval else ('✅'))


        # send command

        signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, _handle_sigttou)
        #signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, signal.SIG_IGN)   # this works without zombies, but I want to print a warning

        threading.Thread(target=_run_shell_command, args=(_line, 60), daemon=True).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.write_event_value(event, value)` to send an event to your window, then maybe call `sg.popup` to show the `value` when `event` in your event loop. Not try to update GUI on your thread.

```py
...

def _handle_sigttou(signum, frame):
    window.write_event_value("<SIGTTOU>", ("WARNING", "<SIGTTOU> received"))
...

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "<SIGTTOU>":
        title, message = values[event]
        sg.popup(message, title=title, auto_close=True, auto_close_duration=2)

window.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, I think i stripped my code example a little bit too much (just updated it a little bit). The threads don't write to the GUI directly. I think this problem is not so much related to PySimpleGUI as far as I understand it.